# How to navigate back to parent page from inside an custom component in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Greeting everyone,
I'm writing a React Native application and have stumbled into something interesting.

This is the simplified version of my code:

```js
//import statements
...

const Profile = (props) => {
    return(
       <Text>Hey {props.name}!</Text>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack();}>Go back</TouchableOpacity>
);}

export function ScreenOne({ navigation }) {
    <Profile name="HUFF">
}
export function ScreenTwo({ navigation }) {
    //blah blah blah
}

export default function App(){
    //rest of the code
    ...
}
```

So basically, I'm trying to use react-navigation to navigate between screens of my App. But the button inside of my `Profile` component doesn't work.

Consider that I navigate from `ScreenTwo` to `ScreenOne`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React navigation has [`useNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) hook

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
// if you are not using react-navigation 5 or 6
// then there is package https://github.com/react-navigation/hooks

const Profile = (props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return(
       <Text>Hey {props.name}!</Text>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>Go back</TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, you might have to specify `navigation` via props on the `Profile` JSX tag, so it can access the parent's `navigation` inside the component. E.g.:

```js
//import statements
...

const Profile = (props) => {
    return(
       <Text>Hey {props.name}!</Text>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>Go back</TouchableOpacity>
    );
}

function ScreenOne({ navigation }) {
   <Profile name="HUFF" navigation={navigation}>
}

function ScreenTwo({ navigation }) {
    //blah blah blah
}

export default function App(){
    //rest of the code
    ...
}
```